# How do I remove all elements for which a pred returns true from a vector using remove_if?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a `vector<GameObject*> gameObjects;`, and want to remove all game objects for which are "dead", determined by this predicate:

```
bool IsDead (GameObject* g)
{
    return g->dead;
}
```

where dead is a boolean member variable of GameObject.

In order to achieve this, I run this function:

```
void Level::undertake() //remove the dead
{
    remove_if(gameObjects.begin(), gameObjects.end(), IsDead);
}
```

However this doesn't work. Why not? On top of this I would like to be able to have that memory space entirely cleared, and not just the pointer removed from the array. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "doesn't work". Also, have a look at the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: I mean that the line of code runs, but has no effect whatsoever as far as I can see.

Comment: Then post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If it has no effect whatsoever you have a bug somewhere else, or no object is dead.

Comment: wait a second, I'm doing some reading on erase-remove idiom. I remeber going over this when learning c++, and I think I will be able to answer my own question. Thanks for the reminder @juanchopanza

Comment: If the `remove_if` has no effect then erase-remove won't do anything.

Comment: use your code with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameObject> > gameObjects;` and your remove_if results in freeing your pointers' memory

Comment: what would just remove_if do in this case? Because it could be having an effect I can't immediately tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
gameObjects.resize(remove_if(gameObjects.begin(), gameObjects.end(), IsDead) - gameObjects.begin());
```

EDIT:
1) `erase` actually is acceptable too, like this:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator end = std::remove_if(vi.begin(), vi.end(), f);
vi.erase(end, vi.end());
```

but resize version is shorter.
2) try something like

```
template <typename T>
struct free_value { void operator()(T* ptr) { delete ptr; } };
std::for_each(end, gameObjects.end(), del<Game>());
```

Comment: If the `remove_if` really has no effect, this won't help.

Comment: It worked. Can you explain what's going on here? I haven't come across the "resize" function before. Thank you

Comment: @juanchopanza If all dead objects are already at the end, then it's certainly possible that `remove_if` has no effect, but that this answer still works. Yaxlat: `remove_if` really doesn't remove anything, it just moves the to-be-removed objects to the end, so that you can then use a single real remove operation (possibly using `resize` as shown in this answer) to actually get rid of them.

Comment: @Yaxlat `remove_if` returns an iterator to the end of the cleared range. The size of the original vector is left untouched, the elements are only shifted. Difference between the returned iterator and the `begin()` is actually the size of the cleaned vector. Consider looking at the real implementation, it's quite short.

Comment: Oh yes, in this case coincidentially, all of the "dead" objects were at the end. Thanks a lot for explaining this! Two more quick things: why do you use "resize" instead of "erase", and how can I then free the memory the space of the pointers (without using unique_ptr, that's not an option here)?

Comment: 1) erase can actually be simplified to 1 line:
vi.erase(std::remove_if(vi.begin(), vi.end(), f), vi.end());

Comment: 2) I dont understand the line: void std::for_each(end, gameObjects.end(), del<Game>());

Comment: `end` is the result of `remove_if` del<Game>() is a function object, that's getting called on every object from range [`end`, `gameObjects.end()`)

Comment: @Yaxlat 2) there shouldn't be `void`, fixed the answer